# Feed features for the Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

According to the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556736/how-to-save-sift-feature-vector-for-classification-using-neural-network), I was able to save features set using the method that has been provided.

```
FeaturesTest.roundness = roundness;    
FeaturesTest.nWhite = nWhite;   
FeaturesTest.color = color;   
FeaturesTest.descriptors = descriptors;  
FeaturesTest.outputs =  outputs;   
FeaturesTest = {roundness,nWhite, color, descriptors, outputs};
```

Now my first 4 features are input to neural network and the 5th one is the target. I wrote like this.

```
load('features.mat','FeaturesTest');  
A = FeaturesTest;   
P=A(:,1:4)';  
T=A(:,5:5)';  
rand('seed', 491218382);  
net = newff(minmax(P),T,20);
```

Now the same error comes for input features...

> ??? Error using ==> horzcat CAT
>   arguments dimensions are not
>   consistent. Error in ==> minmax at 38
>   pr{i} = minmax([p{i,:}]);

Does anyone have an idea of this please?

---

@Itamar Katz Thanks for showing me the both usage of cell array and struct. I changed it now. There is a function like this which returns features for an one image. for roundness and nWhite only one value is coming. descriptors are the shift descriptors. 5 types of outputs are there. for the first image output should be 1, for the second, 2 and so on. color is display like this in .mat file [196,186,177]. output is something like [1,0,0,0,0].

```
function[FeaturesTest] = features(image)
[siftImage, descriptors, locs] = sift(image); 
FeaturesTest = {roundness, nWhite, color, descriptors, outputs};
```

Now take one by one image from training set and call above function for each image.

```
for i=1:size(list, 1);
    if (~(list(i).isdir))
        [FeatureSet] = features(fullfile('F:\ProjectWork\Coin_Recognition\TrainingSet', list(i).name));
        Features = [Features; FeatureSet];
    end
end
save('features.mat','Features');
```

Now I want to train this features. What I did was

```
load('features.mat','Features');
A = Features;
P=A(:,1:4)';
T=A(:,5:5)';
rand('seed', 491218382);
net = newff(minmax(P),T,20);
Error comes here.
```

Please help me. Thanks.

features.mat file for 6 images is like this

```
0.776914651509411   1874    [196,186,177]   <14x128 double>
    [1,0,0,0,0]
0.839974548665116   1794    [219,213,202]   <7x128 double>
    [1,0,0,0,0]
0.841707612525928   1796    [192,182,171]   <5x128 double>
    [1,0,0,0,0]
0.861761793121658   1783    [202,199,192]   <13x128 double>
    [1,0,0,0,0]
0.411077484660635   3689    [97,88,72]  <238x128 double>
    [0,1,0,0,0]
0.844865287736163   3372    [166,139,89]    <228x128 double>
    [0,1,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked to suggested using either a cell array, **or** a struct with fields, but you are doing **both**, and your last line:

```
FeaturesTest = {roundness,nWhite, color, descriptors, outputs};
```

just overwrites `FeaturesTest` making it a cell array, so all the lines before are irrelevant.

I am guessing you need something like this:

```
P = [roundness(:), nWhite(:), color(:), descriptors(:)];
T = outputs(:);
```

However, if you give information regarding the dimension of each field, it would be easier to help you find the error.

Comment: Thanks. In the feature extraction function features are returned like this.  FeaturesTest.nWhite = nWhite;  FeaturesTest.descriptors = descriptors;  FeaturesTest.roundness = roundness;   FeaturesTest.color = color; FeaturesTest.outputs = outputs; then FeaturesTest = {roundness, nWhite, color, descriptors};  Let's say for a one image roundness is <1x1 double> color is <1x3 double> nWhite is <1x1 double> descriptors is <14x128 double> and output is <1x5 double> there are 18 coins going to be trained. so the FeaturesTest with input and output is <18x5 cell>

Comment: please refer my question above. I edited it to give dimensions u requested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at what Itamar Katz is suggesting.

I want to add the following: I think the core of the problem (for both your questions) is that you don't understand that in MATLAB you cannot concatenate matrices of different size.

for example the following is not valid: [ zeros(5,5), ones(4,4) ]

if you try that you will get exactly the same error you're getting.

the matrix(:) operator (see Itemar's answer) converts it into a 1-d array, and therefore many things can be concatenated.

As a suggestion, I pays to take a couple hours to really understand matrices in MATLAB. Then you can advance more efficiently on your work.

Comment: If I cannot concatenate matrices of different sizes, how can I add sift feature descriptors to my features. Before when I train my images, I didn't use this sift feature descriptors and it trained well. Even I didn't use cell array b'cause all features had only 1x1 double value. But, now I want to add this sift descriptor to my features file. according to the keypoints returned from sift algorithm it goes to more than one row, although for other features for an one image only one row is there. Is there any way to get this sift features to one row?

Comment: Is it ok to sum the values in all rows of a particular column returns from sift.? Then for that column I can have only one row? If I do like this, will the functionality of sift work well? I don't have much knowledge of matlab. Can u please help me?