# MATLAB Saving and Loading Feature Vectors

Tags: matlab, image-processing, classification, glcm

I am trying to load feature vectors into classifiers such as a k-nearest neighbors classifier.

I have my code for GLCM, so I get contrast, correlation, energy, homogeneity in numbers (feature vectors).

My question is, how can I save every set of feature vectors from all the training images? I have seen somewhere that people had a .set file to load into classifiers (may be it is a special case for the particular classifier toolbox).

```
load 'mydata.set';
```

for example.

I suppose it does not have to be a .set file.
I'd just need a way to store all the feature vectors from all the training images in a separate file that can be loaded.

I've google, 
[and I found this that may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556736/how-to-save-sift-feature-vector-for-classification-using-neural-network)
but I am not entirely sure.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you arrange your feature vectors as the columns of an array called `X`, then just issue the command

```
save('some_description.mat','X');
```

Alternatively, if you want the save file to be readable, say in ASCII, then just use this instead:

```
save('some_description.txt', 'X', '-ASCII');
```

Later, when you want to re-use the data, just say

```
var = {'X'}; % <-- You can modify this if you want to load multiple variables.

load('some_description.mat', var{:});
load('some_description.txt', var{:}); % <-- Use this if you saved to .txt file.
```

Then the variable named `'X'` will be loaded into the workspace and its columns will be the same feature vectors you computed before.

You will want to replace the `some_description` part of each file name above and instead use something that allows you to easily identify which data set's feature vectors are saved in the file (if you have multiple data sets). Your array of feature vectors may also be called something besides `X`, so you can change the name accordingly.

Comment: thank you so much for answering. 
so do I put the feature vectors of one training image as one file? or just enter the vectors from the same image in the same column?

Comment: for example, in the save file, from training image 1:
X = [7, 5, 3, 1]
or can i combine it with training image 2:
X = [7, 5, 3, 1;
     8, 4, 2, 0]

Comment: My choice would be to combine them, as in your second example. In that case, your syntax is storing the features as rows, but it might be more economical to store them as columns. If you compute many different feature vectors from a single image, you can always save them with a name that references the image. But if you save only one per image, I would concatenate them as columns of `X` and then just save `X` with a descriptive file name. Also, if you think my answer was helpful, please consider up-voting it or accepting it (by clicking the check mark to the left). Thanks!

Comment: please, just out of interest, why is it better to store in columns? is it because so that you would have the same meaning vector each row? (answer accepted, but dont have enough privilege to upvote..lol) thanks a lot once again!

Comment: My thinking is that most operations you will later want to perform on the feature vectors (maybe, say, projecting them to a smaller space with PCA or something) are all operations that work on columns, and you'd have to mess with the standard algorithms to reformat them to operate on rows instead. Otherwise, you'll constantly be transposing your feature vectors any time you want to do something with them. I'm not sure this matters too much, but since you're going ahead and saving them, might as well save them as columns.